# Confusion about the splitting field of $x^3-7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm asked to find the degree of the splitting field of $x^3-7$ over the rationals.

The roots are $\sqrt[3] 7e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{3}},\ k=0,1,2$. Explicitly, $$x_1=\sqrt[3] 7,\\ x_2=\sqrt[3] 7 \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg),\\ x_3=\sqrt[3] 7 \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg).$$

The splitting field is an extension that contains all roots. I see at least two essentially different possibilities of building it. First, I could adjoin $\sqrt[3] 7, i,\sqrt 3$. Such an extension will contain all roots. On the other hand, I could adjoin $\sqrt[3] 7, i\sqrt 3$. This extension also contains all the roots. I believe the two extensions have different degrees. So how should I understand which degree I should find to begin with? Which extension is the splitting field?

Comment: The splitting field should be the one with lowest degree of extension, shouldn't it?  Which field of the two has a smaller degree?

Comment: @Batominovski For example in the Wikipedia definition, I don't see the requirement on the degree.

Comment: Yes, the degrees of the two extension are different. So one of them is not the splitting field. You can think about it as follows. The number $x_2/x_1=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$ is certainly in the splitting field. Because $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subset of the splitting field you can then deduce that $i\sqrt{3}$ must be in. But, it stops there, right?

Comment: On the wiki page, that is said in literally the first sentence of the page.  "In abstract algebra, a splitting field of a polynomial with coefficients in a field is a ***smallest*** field extension of that field over which the polynomial splits or decomposes into linear factors."

Comment: @Batominovski I looked in the "Definition" section. Is it implied by some condition in the formal definition stated on wiki?

Comment: Yes, "[...] the roots $a_i$ ***generate*** $L$ over $K$."

Comment: I saw this condition, but I cannot see how it implies that that extension is the smallest.

Comment: I think it should be your task to prove that my last quote is equivalent to that the extension is smallest.  It is not difficult.  You will understand more about splitting fields that way.

Comment: I guess this holds by the very definition, because $K(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ is defined to be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $K$ and the $a_i$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field $K$ of $x^3-7$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]7, \omega)$, where $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ is a primitive cubic root of the unity, a root of $x^2+x+1$.
There is no need to decompose $\omega$ into $i$ and $\sqrt 3$.

It is true that $L =\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]7, i, \sqrt 3)$ contains all the roots of $x^3-7$, but $L$ is not the *smallest* such field. That is $K$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x^3-7$ and $\alpha=\sqrt [ 3 ]{ 7 }$ is a clear root of $x^3-7$. Then after factoring and applying the quadratic formula $($if needed$)$ one factors $x^3-7=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha\zeta )(x-\alpha\zeta ^2)$ where $\zeta $ is a complex cube root of unity. $\zeta ^2+\zeta +1=0$ and $\zeta \notin\mathbb{R}$ hence $\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, so splitting the field has the degree $3\cdot2=6$. In fact the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\zeta)$.